# Keeping outdoor cat away from my indoor cat

Tags: cats, safety, aggression

Is there anything i can do to prevent an outdoor cat from my window that is eye level? My Cat is an indoor cat and the two are fighting through my screen.

Comment: Please dicribe the Window from the outside. Has it a board? How could the outside cat access it? Is the glass from the floor or begins higher?

Comment: Tried the plastic spikes they use to deter pigeons?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

If the only place the cats can contact each other is the window, I would try spraying or placing something on the window that has a strong scent. This could include a nice big spray of air freshener, some vinegar, a cut lemon/lemon juice, or something similar.

This should hopefully deter them from getting near the window before a fight can take place, and eventually they should learn not to go to the window.